# Puedo salvar dadtos de una div sin input en un banco de datos?

Tags: php

tengo un formulario con algunos `inputs type=hidden`y dentro de este form tengo tambien unas div de esta manera:

> ```
> <div id="1" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" focusable="true" tabindex="-1" class="seatCharts-seat seatCharts-cell first-class unavailable">1</div>
> ```

Estas div forman un mapa de asientos de un autobus y una funcion en jquery que marcar la div como disponible, ocupada o selecionado como puedo insertar ese checkbox  de estas div en mi banco de datos?

Answer (score 0):

La variable miform seria el ID del form, este mismo llevara todos los inputs relacionados dentro de el, y en tu archivo PHP lo puedes obtener con la variable $_POST['nombre_del_input']. no se te olvide pescribir en la funcion jquery el  **event.preventDefault();** para que no te recargue la pagina si asi lo deseas

```
var miform= document.getElementById("miform");
var miformData= new FormData(miform);
$.ajax({
    url: "tu_archivo.php",
    data: miformData,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        // hacer algo con la respuesta
    }
});
```

Comment: buenas, muchas gracias por responder, este codigo me esta ayudando bastante. Pero como haria con las div que tienen el atributo role="checkbox" para que cuando esten selecionados sea insertado en la tabla de mi DB su valor?